# How can I figure out where a Python Segmentation fault comes from?

Tags: python, pyqt5, segmentation-fault

I have a somewhat complex logging program, which I used to run for months in a row without crashes or problems. But recently I am getting - about once per day - crashes of this kind:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is the sole error output I can see. It says "core dumped" but whereto? I found no dump file anywhere.

I tested all Python versions 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12 - it may take a while to get this crash, but eventually it happens in all versions. I suspect PyQt5, but this is really gut feeling only.

What can I do about finding the cause of the Segmentation fault?

Comment: Testing with different Python versions is very unlikely to be much help. You need to test different Qt/PyQt versions (and possibly on different platforms if you can). There's no reliable way to find the source of a seg-fault without debug builds of all the relevant libaries (which means both Qt and PyQt, and possibly Python as well). If you're on Linux, your distro may already have pre-built debug packages. You can then use e.g. [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) to try to get a stack backtrace.

Comment: This kind of error is very common in low-level languages such as C, C++. It normally happens when you're trying to access/write on non-allocated memory. As I test my scripts on windows, when there's a similar crash of this type nothing is printed on the console, so I can't say the same for linux: maybe you're trying to use garbage collected memory somewhere on your application. It's very easy to do that in python + qt (which is bad), as it's mainly an event-based framework. Though without an actual example we can only guess what's happening on your side.

Comment: Thanks for the bad news :-(
As it says "(core dumped)" - is there actually anything "dumped"? I understand this as a file saved to somewhere, but if so I can't find this file.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277339). You'll need to use gdb as ekhumoro sugested. Beyond this point I'm unable to help as I've never used it. Good luck.

Comment: @ullix There is no "bad news". As I explained above, you need to install debug builds of at least Qt and PyQt in order to get reliable information about the source of a seg-fault. The core-dump file won't be much use without debug symbols. Also, your system may not be configured to save core-dump files - and even if it does, those files are usually automatically deleted after a few days. But that won't matter if you run your program in a debugger and request a backtrace after it seg-faults. If you're using ubuntu, see: [Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages).

Comment: Thanks, folks, but I am afraid I have to pass on this - beyond my pay-grade!
In the meantime I took a wild guess and at least so far it worked. If really true then it was a "repaint" problem of calling from different places in PyQt5.